# Searching in google sheet using app script not working with numbers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use app script to give access to my Google sheet by searching through a webpage. so I don't have to give all the data. the search is based on a specific column and the result can be repeatable on the column itself but the other columns of the same row like price and item are different.

with my current code if the searched column has only characters the code works perfectly but once I add numbers to the targeted column on my google sheet the code stop working .. can you help me with that .. my knowledge is basic with coding

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate()
  .setTitle("WebApp: Search By Password")
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){ 
  var concat = formObject.searchtext;
  var result = "";
  if(concat){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(concat);
  }
  return result;
}


function search(searchtext = 'searchtext') {
  let ar = [];
 var spreadsheetId   = '1aN8VLL4iKhGjmM84qhncG9cQfKigCWscMT-UkdzNhQs'; 
  const names = ['Data', 'Data2'];
  names.forEach((name) => {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name).getDataRange();
    var data = range.getValues();
    data.forEach(function (f) {
    if (f[0] === searchtext) {
      ar.push([f[0],f[1],f[2],f[3],f[4],f[5],f[6],f[7],f[8],f[9]]);
      }
      
    });
  });
  return ar;
};
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `f[0] == searchtext` because `===` says the same object type and the same value.  It may be preventing `searchtext` to being coerced into a number.